# Happy end of year?

Tags: idiomatic-language, translation

In Spanish, it's not uncommon to wish people a good "fin de año" (e.g.: "Hope you're able to enjoy the end of year!"). This isn't the same as wishing people a happy New Year, since it's not exactly about the next year, nor is it about New Year's Eve, since it can encompass the whole month of December, maybe even November.

Is this directly translatable to English or would it be necessary to adapt the sentence to make it idiomatic? (e.g.: "Hope you're able to enjoy the rest of this year!") Would "happy end of year / year end / year's end" be grammatical and idiomatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no comparable standard expression in English that I'm aware of. The only expression I know to denote the end of the year is "Happy New Years", which is very common after Christmas until mid-January.

Saying something like, "*Hope you're able to enjoy the end of year!*" or "*Hope you're able to enjoy the rest of this year!*" both sound like something horrible might happen to that person before the year is over, and they might not be able to enjoy it.

All the expressions "*happy end of year / year end / year's end*" are grammatical, but none are idiomatic. In particular, "[year end](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/year-end)" is an often-dreaded financial term, so not what you want to wish to someone.

If you're saying goodbye, "Enjoy the rest of the year!" would sound natural enough, though it is not common.